как вывести пользователя, нажавшего на кнопку
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__(timeout=None)
        self.value = Optional[bool]

  @disnake.ui.button(label="Одобрить", style=disnake.ButtonStyle.green, custom_id='accept')
    async def first_button_callback(self, button: disnake.ui.Button, interaction: disnake.MessageInteraction):
        await interaction.response.send_message('Вы успешно одобрили запрос', ephemeral=True)
        await interaction.message.delete()
        self.value = True
        self.stop()

    @disnake.ui.button(label="Отказать", style=disnake.ButtonStyle.red, custom_id='cancel')
    async def second_button_callback(self, button: disnake.ui.Button, interaction: disnake.MessageInteraction):
        await interaction.response.send_message('Вы успешно отказали запрос', ephemeral=True)
        await interaction.message.delete()
        self.value = False
        self.stop()


@bot.slash_command(description='Снять фракционную роль с участника')
async def remove(inter, user: disnake.User, reason: str):
    view = MyView()
    mention = user.mention
    id = user.id
    nick = user.nick

    if user.get_role(1218120021931200573):
        embed = disnake.Embed(
            title='`Discord >> Запрос на снятие роли`'
        )
        embed.add_field(name="Пользователь:", value=f"{mention}", inline=False)
        embed.add_field(name="Ник:", value=f"{nick}", inline=True)
        embed.add_field(name="Роль:", value="<@&1218120021931200573>", inline=True)
        embed.add_field(name="Причина:", value=f"{reason}", inline=True)

        await inter.send(embed=embed, view=view)

        await view.wait()
        if view.value is True:
            await inter.send(f'`[ACCEPT] Запрос на снятие роли (⋆ Los-Santos Police Departament ⋆) от ` {inter.author.mention} ` пользователю ` {user.mention} `  его ID `||{user.id}||` был одобрен`')
            role = disnake.utils.get(user.guild.roles, id=1218120021931200573)
            await user.remove_roles(role)
        else:
            await inter.send(f'`[CANCEL] Запрос на снятие роли (⋆ Los-Santos Police Departament ⋆) от ` {inter.author.mention} ` пользователю ` {user.mention} `  его ID `||{user.id}||` был отказан`')
    elif user.get_role(1218120207000670309):
        embed = disnake.Embed(
            title='`Discord >> Запрос на снятие роли`'
        )
        embed.add_field(name="Пользователь:", value=f"{mention}", inline=False)
        embed.add_field(name="Ник:", value=f"{nick}", inline=True)
        embed.add_field(name="Роль:", value="<@&1218120207000670309>", inline=True)
        embed.add_field(name="Причина:", value=f"{reason}", inline=True)

        await inter.send(embed=embed, view=view)

        await view.wait()
        if view.value is True:
            await inter.send(
                f'`[ACCEPT] Запрос на снятие роли (⋆ San-Fierro Medical Center ⋆) от ` {inter.author.mention} ` пользователю ` {user.mention} `  его ID `||{user.id}||` был одобрен`')
            role = disnake.utils.get(user.guild.roles, id=1218120207000670309)
            await user.remove_roles(role)
        else:
            await inter.send(
                f'`[CANCEL] Запрос на снятие роли (⋆ San-Fierro Medical Center ⋆) от ` {inter.author.mention} ` пользователю ` {user.mention} `  его ID `||{user.id}||` был отказан`')
    else:
        await inter.send('У человека не найдено ни одной из фракционных ролей', ephemeral=True)```


  @disnake.ui.button(label="Одобрить", style=disnake.ButtonStyle.green, custom_id='accept')
    async def first_button_callback(self, button: disnake.ui.Button, interaction: disnake.MessageInteraction):

    print(interaction.user) #Вывод в консоль пользователя, нажавшего на кнопку.

